# Blonde hair looking green at certain angle

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I have a friend who has blonde hair. And when look at an oblique angle, there's a tinge of light green in her hair. I've heard that the copper ion in pool water can make blonde hair green, but her hair had always been like that. Besides, it's not really green hair, but more like a green glow.

So is it possible that the cuticles on the hair strand acted like a diffraction grating, and somehow only the green portion of the spectrum can be seen?

Additional information: I have to look almost horizontally facing the sun to see the green glow. And it was 1 o'clock in the afternoon, so I'd say the solar elevation angle is about 70 degrees.

Comment: Here's some images of diffraction in [dandelions](http://www.atoptics.co.uk/fz1006.htm) and [feathers](http://www.atoptics.co.uk/fz901.htm). Not sure how to explain selection for green. It'd be interesting if you were able to take a photo!

Comment: @rob I can see the glow right there but I can't see it through my phone. I guess my cellphone camera's not good enough. Maybe this question is too specific to the system. Nice pics!

Comment: We just had a [really interesting question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111006/44126) where a funny optical effect turned out *not* to be diffraction; don't be afraid to come back if you are eventually able to get a good photograph.

Comment: Does your friend dye her hair or use conditioner? There are many possible reasons for what you are describing: if you see this in sunlight at a low angle, I would venture to guess it's a fluorescence effect from the conditioner. But without more data it is nothing more than a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason must be the fact that the Green light is bending at most. Well the blue bends even more, but it's also an issue what you can really see. The same effect can be seen in sunset, and it's called [Green flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_flash).

This picture from the German-language Wiki explains this at best;

[image]

So there should be, and even is, also all the other colors in other positions, but these you can't see cause the sun is too near and shines you blind, or at the case of blue, it's simply too weak compared to the scattered light coming from various directions.