# Why is the shadow behaving like this?

Tags: visible-light, refraction, home-experiment, shadow

When approaching a sheet of paper between the sun and an object (a Lego here) the shadow of the object seems to get bigger [as in this video](https://youtu.be/I9QiMr377FI).

Can you please explain why?

Thank you! :)

Comment: [Possibly related?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111006/how-does-light-bend-around-my-finger-tip)

Comment: Thanks, it does answer the question, sorry for not finding it before posting.